# Automapper: map List<string> to List<Class>

Tags: automapper

How can I map a `List<string>` to `List<Class>`?

Usecase: from the Webservice I'm getting a class with a list of string but in my MVC Viewmodel, I want to have Class instead with a single property, which has the value of the string. That way I can add Validation attributes to the property.

I have the way how I convert the List into a List, however I can't get the other way around to work.

Any simple solutions?

Comment: what format is the string?

Comment: a standard c# string, Nothing special about it

Comment: Why don't you do the conversion with Linq?

Comment: @Daniel A. White how do you mean I should do that?

Comment: Or have a look at model binding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to do this with AutoMapper is to use `.ConstructUsing`:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<string, Class>()
    .ConstructUsing(str => new Class { MyProp = str });
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Vlc8b

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do it with Linq.

```
var newList = oldList.Select(x => new Item(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: and how do I add this in the Automapper CreateMap? Can yu porvice a full example?

Comment: @Stefan - Keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do this:

```
void Main()
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<string,A>()
              .ForMember(a => a.Name, m => m.MapFrom(s => s));

    new[] {"A", "B"}.Select (AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<A>).Dump();
}

class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

(Linqpad code)

But I think this can go down as a textbook example of over-engineering. Just do it as in Daniel's example.

Answer (score 0):

If sometimes without any much reason. below code might not work..

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, Class>()
    .ConstructUsing(str => new Class { MyProp = str });
```

Try. AfterMap function in the AutoMapper package to do that. It worked for me.

Ex:

```
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                {
                    // Manual mapping for Class.
                    dest.StudentNames= src.StudentNames.Select(value => new Class { StudentNames= value }).ToList();
                    // Perform other manual mappings if needed
                })
```

Hope it helps.